# Difficulty with making multiple api / http node.js requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I've gotten two api requests to work individually but I'm having a lot of trouble to get them both working on my node.js app. Is there an easy way to make two requests ? I've tried making two requests putting the data into a variable and then rendering both of them but I run into issues with global variables. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  request(url, function (err, response, body) {

    if(err){
      res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
    } else {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body);

      if(weather.main == undefined){
        res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
      } else {
        if (rain == "0,rain"){
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees celsius and with wind speeds of ${weather.wind.speed} mph in ${weather.name} ${weather.sys.country}! & ${weather.weather[0].description}`  ;
        res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null});
      }
      else{
        let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees celsius and with wind speeds of ${weather.wind.speed} mph in ${weather.name} ${weather.sys.country}!`  ;
        res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null});
      }
      }
    }

  });
```

```
request(url2, function (err, response, body) {
  if(err){
    res.render('index', {news: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
  } else {
    let result = JSON.parse(body);
    let news = result.articles[0].title
    if(news == undefined){
      res.render('index', {news: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
    } 
    else{

      res.render('index', {news:news, error: null});
    }
    }
  })
```

Comment: How about nesting the requests?

Comment: I’m on a mobile so can’t be of much help, but I would suggest looking at promises as a way of waiting for a response from your first call, and then firing a second call based on the response from the first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ‘promise’ to wait until a response has been received from your first request. Once this has happened, you can trigger your second request, (see ‘then’ on the link below). Once your second request returns a result, you can combine the response from both requests, before using the data.

If request B needs to use data from the response of request A, then request A should be first in the chain. This allows you to adjust your second request based on the response from the first e.g. with IF statements. If the two are completely independent,  you can pick either request to go first.

There is a section on this link about chaining promises, which should be relevant to what you’re trying to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Details about error handling with promises and ‘catch’ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: I haven't covered anything with promises before but I'll have a look over and see if I can figure out how to implement it

Comment: I used them for the first time on a recent project myself, so I could use promise.all to manage a queue of requests. Took a bit of time to wrap my head around how they work but definitely something worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual need to use promises, although they do simplify code structure, you can just a easily nest requests:

```
request(url, function(err, response, body) {
    request(url2, function(err2, response2, body2) {
        // Both request data is available here
    })
})
```

Note that the variable names used in the callback function can be changed here

Should you have a bunch of requests that can be ran independently, look into `promise.all`

Comment: Thanks for the help I managed to get it working like that however is there an easy way to handle errors / if nothing gets returned without needing a lot of if statements?

Comment: Error handling can be easily managed with promises. I see the appeal of just nesting the requests, but if error handling is a priority I’d really recommend looking at promises. Have added a link to my answer.

Comment: You'd have to test err and err2 where required on the callback pattern. Promises are a more advanced, but syntax-wise more simpler version of a callback. It really helps understanding callbacks first. An upside of promises is having a general .catch() error handler. Also, a downside of promises is having a general .catch() error handler.